# cs231n: train/val accuracy and number of parameters

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, accuracy

In this [cs231](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#accuracy) lection note there is a counterintuitive quote:

> The gap between the training and validation accuracy indicates the amount of overfitting.
>
> ...
>
> The other possible case is when the validation accuracy tracks the training accuracy fairly well. This case indicates that your model capacity is not high enough: make the model larger by increasing the number of parameters.

[image]

**Questions**:

1. Isn't the goal of training to achieve the validation accuracy as high as training accuracy or did I miss something?
2. What the intuition under increasing the number of parameters if the validation accuracy tracks the training accuracy fairly well?

Answer (score 1):

I think this:

> The other possible case is when the validation accuracy tracks the training accuracy fairly well. This case indicates that your model capacity is not high enough: make the model larger by increasing the number of parameters.

Is getting at the idea that training a model, in general, should yield overfitting. That is basically its design -- tweak weights until error is zero.

So, if your model is NOT overtly overfitting, then your model can probably "learn more" with more trainable parameters which in turn, should, help you get even better validation metrics.

Comment: I got the idea. Thanks

Are there any techniques to solve the trade-off between min training loss and min train/val difference in loss? IOW, when should I stop tweaking the weights?

Comment: You should freeze weights when you maximize or minimize whatever training objective you have. If it is loss, then whenever you reach the minimum. If it is F1, then whenever you reach the maximum.